# Monte Carlo Integration with manipulate

Tags: numerical-integration, manipulate

I did a manipulate algorithm to see how Monte Carlo Integration precision works, using as example the Cauchy Function.

When Dynamic Updating is enabled, the resulting MC calculation keeps evaluating. Why?

```
funcCauchy[X_, A_] := Module[{x = X, a = A}, 1/(1 + (x/a)^2)];     



Manipulate[
     b = 2.;
     a = -2.;
     c = 1.5;
     n = 0;
     X = 0;
     Y = 0;
     data = Do[
       X = RandomReal[{-2, 2}];
       Y = RandomReal[{0, 1.5}];
       fx = funcCauchy[X, 2];
       If[Y < fx, n = n + 1],
        Num];

     TextCell[
      Column[{{"resultado da Integração de f (x, a) = 1/(1 + (x/a)^2) é  \
    = ", Integrate[
          1/(1 + (x/2.)^2), {x, -2, 
           2}]}, {"resultado da Integração por Monte Carlo, com N= ", Num,
          " é igual a = ", 
         N[Integ = (b - a)*c *(n/Num), {Infinity, 6}]}}], FontSize -> 12, 
      TextAlignment -> Left, CellFrame -> True, 
      CellMargins -> {{300, 300}, {20, 20}}],
     {{Num, 10, "N = N\[Degree]. de Rodadas"}, Appearance -> "Open", 10, 
      10^5, 100}, ContinuousAction -> False, ContentSize -> {700, 100}

 ]
```

Please, be free to improve this manipulate algorithm settings!

Comment: Have you tried `TrackedSymbols`?

Comment: Did not  work, TrackedSymbols :> {num}

Comment: Well first you need to make sure the symbol you are tracking is exactly the same as the one you are using (so `Num` rather than `num`).  You will also want to consider if any other symbols should trigger an update.

Comment: Oh, Thanks! It worked, TrackedSymbols :> {Num}. :)

Comment: @lowriniak Make it a full answer and I will upvote it. Didn't know about this option and find it quite useful, too :-)

Comment: @locometro De onde você é? Estou buscando uns contatos brasileiros por aqui

Comment: Petrópolis - RJ

Comment: Beleza. Sou de São José dos Campos - SP. Até mais. É legal saber que tem brasileiro que usa este programa.

Comment: As ordens ! Uso desde 2004.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Expanding on my comment, if you have a `Manipulate` that continually refreshes or has poor performance issues, you will need to do some evaluation control.  In this case the option you need is `TrackedSymbols` which is given to the whole `Manipulate`.  In this case you would write:

```
funcCauchy[X_, A_] := Module[{x = X, a = A}, 1/(1 + (x/a)^2)];     

Manipulate[
     (*These are currently global variables so you also may want to add LocalizeVariables -> True as well*)
     b = 2.; a = -2.; c = 1.5; n = 0; X = 0; Y = 0;
     data = Do[
       X = RandomReal[{-2, 2}];
       Y = RandomReal[{0, 1.5}];
       fx = funcCauchy[X, 2];
       If[Y < fx, n = n + 1],
        Num
     ];

     TextCell[
      Column[{{"resultado da Integração de f (x, a) = 1/(1 + (x/a)^2) é  \
    = ", Integrate[
          1/(1 + (x/2.)^2), {x, -2, 
           2}]}, {"resultado da Integração por Monte Carlo, com N= ", Num,
          " é igual a = ", 
         N[Integ = (b - a)*c *(n/Num), {Infinity, 6}]}}], FontSize -> 12, 
      TextAlignment -> Left, CellFrame -> True, 
      CellMargins -> {{300, 300}, {20, 20}}],

     (*The only control variable is Num*)
     (*Therefore, assuming this is a standalone tool, you only want Num to be tracked for changes*)
     {{Num, 10, "N = N\[Degree]. de Rodadas"}, Appearance -> "Open", 10, 
      10^5, 100}, 
   ContinuousAction -> False, 
   ContentSize -> {700, 100},

  (*TrackedSymbols takes a list of symbols and only updates the Manipulate when one of them changes*)
  (*remember to use RuleDelayed so they are treated as symbols and not their values*)
  TrackedSymbols :> {Num}
]
```